# Serial port problem between esp32 and matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port, esp32, arduino-esp32

I am using esp32 (nodemcu 32s) that connected to mpu9250 module.
The circuit schematic is
[circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ5lA.png)

This is the esp code with arduino ide:

```
/***************************************************************************
* Example sketch for the MPU9250_WE library
***************************************************************************/

#include <MPU9250_WE.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#define MPU9250_ADDR 0x68

MPU9250_WE myMPU9250 = MPU9250_WE(MPU9250_ADDR);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
 delay(200);
 myMPU9250.autoOffsets();
 myMPU9250.setAccOffsets(-14240.0, 18220.0, -17280.0, 15590.0, -20930.0, 12080.0);
  myMPU9250.setGyrOffsets(45.0, 145.0, -105.0);
  myMPU9250.enableGyrDLPF();
  
  myMPU9250.setGyrDLPF(MPU9250_DLPF_6);

  myMPU9250.setSampleRateDivider(5);

  myMPU9250.setGyrRange(MPU9250_GYRO_RANGE_250);

  myMPU9250.setAccRange(MPU9250_ACC_RANGE_2G);

  myMPU9250.enableAccDLPF(true);

  myMPU9250.setAccDLPF(MPU9250_DLPF_6);

  
  myMPU9250.enableAccAxes(MPU9250_ENABLE_XYZ);
  myMPU9250.enableGyrAxes(MPU9250_ENABLE_XYZ);
 
  myMPU9250.setMagOpMode(AK8963_CONT_MODE_100HZ);
  delay(200);
}

void loop() {
  xyzFloat gValue = myMPU9250.getGValues();
  xyzFloat gyr = myMPU9250.getGyrValues();
  xyzFloat magValue = myMPU9250.getMagValues();
  float temp = myMPU9250.getTemperature();
  float resultantG = myMPU9250.getResultantG(gValue);
 //float AccArray[3]={gValue.x , gValue.y , gValue.z};
 // Serial.println(AccArray[3]);
 String pausedata=" ";
 String datatoprint= gValue.x +pausedata+gValue.y+pausedata + gValue.z;
 Serial.println(datatoprint);
delay(200);
}
```

the serial mointor display this after run the esp32
[serial monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV83Z.png)

while matlab code:

```
s=serialport("COM3",115200);
fid=fopen("serialread.txt",'a')
%legimu=[];
%row=0;
while (true)
   % row=row+1;
data=readline(s)
data2 = fscanf(s, '%f%c');
fprintf(fid,data);
%legimu(row,:)=str2num(data);
end
```

the serialread.txt display:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UetV.png)
How can I get the data without the information that appears at the begining. so I can plot the data in real time.

I try to send the data as float array. but the data doesn't display correctly (only 0.00 appears in serial monitor in arduino.
In fact, I am a beginner in arduino. I want to build seven motion capture units (esp32+vibration motor+mpu 9250 sensor) so I can calcutate the subject motion. then the data should be send to matlab that send the allowed motion range and plot the  angles in real time. if the motion angles out of motion range the vibration motor will vibes.
I want to convert this esp to router and use the serial port to display all recieved data from other esps to matlab for displaying data plots in real time and send commands to the esps.
I could not use Wifi with matlab.
if any suggestion to solve these problems

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the additional data because you are using the same serial port for logging (what you see in the Arduino serial monitor) and to send your data to MATLAB, so you also see all the logging messages in MATLAB.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Use a different serial port to send your data to MATLAB. This would require modifying your circuit and using a UART serial to USB adapter.
2. Filter what you read in MATLAB, to ignore all the logging messages and process only the messages with your expected format.

Comment: Thank you 
The first suggestion I think It would take some time for modifying. I'll try the second one.